# saving file in internal storage android for my app

Tags: java, android-studio

I have audio mp3 in res/raw/suono1.mp3 and i need share(in my app) on whatapp my code is it, but when i send, don t share HELP ME PLS.

```
pulsante2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    //condividere
    InputStream inputStream;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
            inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.suono2);
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sound.mp3"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();

        } 
    catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound.mp3" ));
            intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share audio"));

            return false;
        }
});
```

send code for android studio i need them

Comment: It's fine as long as you are working inside the private memory of your app but you are going to explicitly declare permissions inside your manifest if you want to try something like **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() (No longer your private app memory)**, debug the log and posting the Exceptions would further help you and the rest of the people in understanding your problem

Comment: i have audio in raw can whrite a code for myapp ? i don t speak very well english but i understard code, i need share a audio.mp3 From my App to Whatapp

Comment: Sharing from YourApp To WhatsApp was not a problem for anyone but the accounts. So once you start sniffing around the account access and modifiability rules for WhatsApp through code, this is where holes for vulnerability are created. So WhatsApp filled those holes with **WhatsApp 3rd party integrations and WhatsApp Api Usage is just banned**. Maybe you are trying to write the raw sound to WhatsApp Folder?? If you are looking to store the sound in WhatsApp folders, that is something you can do, but you cannot programmatically broadcast media through or by WhatsApp!!!

Comment: in play store there are a app "Non c é piu vino"in this app through a button you can share the sound of what the app button,I in my app I was trying to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked permission in the manifest.xml file?

Comment: yes  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>